# max_execution_time affecting uploads?

Tags: php, file-upload

Can `max_execution_time` (which I left to the default value of 30) in `php.ini` affect uploads? I set `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` to **20M** and `client_max_body_size` (in nginx) also, but some users keep telling me they have problems uploading files larger than (say) 1M (I/O upload error) whereas they can upload without any issues 400KB files.

Maybe with slow connections the flash(?) script exceeds the 30s limit and the upload isn't finished..?

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: It's WordPress built-in uploader.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No `max_execution_time` does not affect uploads, however `max_input_time` does.

See https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.common-pitfalls.php

Answer (score 0):

No. From the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time):

> The maximum execution time is not affected by system calls, stream operations etc.

Comment: Uh, ok. So maybe the cause is max_input_time? From documentation: max_input_time sets the maximum time, in seconds, the script is allowed to receive input; this includes file uploads. For large or multiple files, or users on slower connections, the default of 60 seconds may be exceeded

Comment: Yes. I didn't know of that one. It's worth a shot I'd say.